# Join Query on Foreign Key that may be null

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

How do you get results (foreign key column null) from a join query where the foreign key could be null in springboot JPA ?

I have two tables courses(parent) and courseTypes(child), course_id is the foreign key and it may be sometimes null, however i want to results irregardless.

**Below is what I have tried**
 `..... join on c.courses.id = ct.courseTypes.course_id .......`

It only works if course_id is not null.

Comment: If the FK is null, that means that there are no related rows to it. What row(s) do you want to "artificially" relate to it?

Comment: `...  left join on c.courses.id = ct.courseTypes.course_id` ?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are using JPA, you deal with java entities with properties and references, not tables and columns. If you are trying to get back Parent instances, you just query for them "select p from Parent p" and JPA will return parent instances with their referenced children (or null if there isn't one). If you need to include the children in the query filter, you would perform a left outer join "select p from Parent p left join p.child c .."